# Azure refresh token expires despite using a confidential client

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, refresh-token

I'm using a Web App/API azure application for a web application and used authorization grant flow with client_id and client_secret to get the access/refresh tokens (using rest API), everything worked fine, except the refresh token that has expired after 90 days. **The expectation is to have a refresh_token that never expires (unless explicitly revoked) as stated in azure documentation.**

This is what Microsoft AzureAD documentation says :
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#refresh-tokens)

> Token lifetimes with confidential client refresh tokens Confidential
> clients are applications that can securely store a client password
> (secret). They can prove that requests are coming from the secured
> client application and not from a malicious actor. For example, a web
> app is a confidential client because it can store a client secret on
> the web server. It is not exposed. Because these flows are more
> secure, the default lifetimes of refresh tokens issued to these flows
> is until-revoked, cannot be changed by using policy, and will not be
> revoked on voluntary password resets.

This the definition of confidential clients based on RFC6749:
(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1)

> Clients capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
> credentials (e.g., client implemented on a secure server with
> restricted access to the client credentials), or capable of secure
> client authentication using other means.

The error I'm getting now on refresh token request :
`AADSTS700082: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity. The token was issued on 2018-10-19T17:26:59.8511467Z and was inactive for 90.00:00:00.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not replacing the old refresh token with a fresh one, which is also provided whenever you make a call to get a new Access token using a refresh token.

The [Refreshing the access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens) page explains this as follows.

> Refresh tokens do not have specified lifetimes. Typically, the
>   lifetimes of refresh tokens are relatively long. However, in some
>   cases, refresh tokens expire, are revoked, or lack sufficient
>   privileges for the desired action. Your application needs to expect
>   and handle errors returned by the token issuance endpoint correctly.
>
> When you receive a response with a refresh token error, discard the
>   current refresh token and request a new authorization code or access
>   token. In particular, when using a refresh token in the Authorization
>   Code Grant flow, if you receive a response with the
>   interaction_required or invalid_grant error codes, discard the refresh
>   token and request a new authorization code.